# Preview panel provider (JavaFX WebView) error after android studio update

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

After updating Android Studio to 4.1, I'm getting the error:

> Tried to use preview panel provider (JavaXx WebView), but it is unavailable. Reverting to default.

Any solution?
[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I solved it by uninstalling `MarkDown` from plugin

Go File > Settings > Plugins
Find Markdown and uninstall it

Comment: It doesn't seem to supported by Android Studio 4.1 though

Comment: I think so, but after uninstalling  project works fine. May be they will fix it in next update.

Comment: @Mukta I cannot press uninstall buttonas it is deactivated. How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi @Tony Brand, Sorry for late reply, I have tried in my three laptops and I am able to install and uninstall. Exit from android studio, reopen and try again. See what's happen than.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution, uninstall MarkDown plugin resolved this issue. AndroidStudion used - Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020

Comment: For those in the near future - @ShahzadAkram below is right, with the latest update it works now.

Answer (score 4):

No need to disable or remove the plugin, this issue isn't anymore in the latest update `201.9274` of the Markdown Plugin.

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX preview was [moved to a plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14250-javafx-runtime-for-plugins).

Default preview mode is now using JCEF (Chromium based web browser component inside the JVM).